# Using the Fastlane Spaceship Tunes can I create a new language for existing app?

Tags: fastlane

I would like to use the Fastlane Spaceship library for the iTunes Connect API to create a new language.  For example, I already have a new version that is editable and has the English (U.S.) language set as primary, I would like to add the language French.  Can I do this programmatically or do I have to use Apple's UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of `deliver`, you can do the following:

```
# Makes sure all languages we need are actually created
def verify_available_languages!(options)
  # Collect all languages we need
  # We only care about languages from user provided values
  # as the other languages are on iTC already anyway
  v = options[:app].edit_version
  UI.user_error!("Could not find a version to edit for app '#{options[:app].name}', the app metadata is read-only currently") unless v

  enabled_languages = []
  LOCALISED_VERSION_VALUES.each do |key|
    current = options[key]
    next unless current && current.kind_of?(Hash)
    current.each do |language, value|
      enabled_languages << language unless enabled_languages.include?(language)
    end
  end

  if enabled_languages.count > 0
    v.create_languages(enabled_languages)
    lng_text = "language"
    lng_text += "s" if enabled_languages.count != 1
    UI.message("Activating #{lng_text} #{enabled_languages.join(', ')}...")
    v.save!
  end
  true
end
```

So basically use this method to create a new language:

```
v.create_languages(enabled_languages)
```

Comment: Unfortunately enough `app = Spaceship.app.find(id)` and `app.edit_version` returns error, apparently you can't change the edit_version from spaceship terminal? Thanks for pointing out how it's done in the library though.